# fbAsyncInit fires in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having some issues getting fbAsyncInit to fire in Chrome, though I can see it fires in Firefox (through the alert).

I've read some stackoverflow questions/answers and found that many traced it back to channelUrl. For the channelUrl, I've tried removing it altogether (as it should be optional) and I've tried using a .php file as well as a .html file containing the proper  as mentioned in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ under channel file).

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
var appID = '353110578113914';
    var redirectURI = 'http://localhost/fb/logged-in.html';
    var php = true;
    var channel = 'http://localhost/fb/channel.php';

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    alert('fbAsyncInit was called');

    FB.init({
      appId      : appID, // App ID
      channelUrl : channel, // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was using a Chrome extension called Facebook Disconnect. The moment I disabled, everything worked fine. :/

Comment: Happened the same to me, but using ghostery in firefox. Careful!